# Fluent Nhibernate return ORA-06413 Connection not open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate

I have some web application that using Fluent NHibernate as the ORM and ORACLE 11g as the database.

Below is my Configuration Builder look a like

```
return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ora"))
                                .AdoNetBatchSize(100)
                                .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver>()
                         )
                .Mappings(mappings => mappings.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMapping>())
                //.ExposeConfiguration(ReCreateSchema)
                .BuildConfiguration();
```

And below is my Connection String

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ora" connectionString="Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=serviceName)));User Id=uidxx;Password=pwdxx;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

From the configuration, the next step is build the session factory

```
ISessionFactory sesionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Whenever I run the application, it will throw an error with code

> **ORA-06413: Connection not Open**

Is there any configuration that I miss? I'm also try to research for the solution but found nothing. And also I try to replace the configuration with `OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10` but I got the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and did some trial/error (sigh)
Found that I must change the configuration builder into like this

```
return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(OracleManagedDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ora"))
                                .AdoNetBatchSize(100)
                                .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleManagedDataClientDriver>()
                         )
                .Mappings(mappings => mappings.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMapping>())
                //.ExposeConfiguration(ReCreateSchema)
                .BuildConfiguration();
```

And also I must to install the ORACLE DATA PROVIDER for NET Framework ([ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)) before I build this application.